# How to change height width of uib carousel?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab, uib

i used uib carousel in angular js ,for slide video in every 5 sec. for that used object element to embed video in that using vlc plugin.but porblem is that uib carousel have fixed height and width. how i change it and make it response.

if i use image in carousel that it simple to change height of it but when  i used object tag than it not change the height .

i used it like this

```
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
      <div >
        <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
          <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
            <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc">
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" name="vlc" />
</object>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
              <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
          </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this lines from bootstrap.min.css to change height and width
**before**

```
.carousel { position: relative }
.carousel-inner { position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden }
.carousel-inner>.item { position: relative; display: none; -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left; -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left; transition: .6s ease-in-out left }
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img { line-height: 1 }
```

**After**

```
.carousel { position: absolute;height:100%;min-height: 100%;width:100%; }
.carousel-inner { position: relative; width: 100%; height:100%;min-height: 100%;}
.carousel-inner>.item {height:100%;min-height: 100%; position: relative; display: none; -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left; -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out left; transition: .6s ease-in-out left;width:100%; }
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img { line-height: 1 }
```